# Counting instances a substring shows up

Tags: python, methods, count, substring

An newbie programmer taking a CS class. Using Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 14.04 with a HPmini(Atom processor) laptop. **How many 'ana' are in** **"Canada's banana analysis"** The sought out result should be **4** not 3, banana has 2 instances of 'ana'.  // f.find() will give me the index, no good.
Is there a way to slice the search loop inside a for loop such as: **if i[n:n+4] == 'ana':** ? So that at each iteration it looks forward 3 characters and does the test 'blah=='ana':  // what methods are needed. Thank you in advance for looking into this. Don't need the exact answer just the idea.
my present/closest code is:

```
  g="Canada's bananas analysis"  # main string
  b='ana'                        # sub-string to be found
  anaSt=g.count(b)               # meant to count instances of 'ana'
  lenG=len(g)                    #length of main string
  k=0
  for i in range(lenG):
      if 'ana' in g:
          k +=1
          print 'k: ', k,
  print '\n', lenG
  print "'ana' in string: ",anaSt
```

Comment: Can you describe how to determine the number in human language? Do that first (a.k.a. known as writing pseudocode) and then translate these steps to Python.

Comment: Perhaps spelling "analysis" correctly will give you that fourth match that you seem to think should be there?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: You need to increment `range` by 1 to catch overlapping `ana` in `banana`.

Comment: @dawg: you're right. This should do it `sum(1 for i in range(len(g)) if g[i:i+3] == 'ana')`

Comment: when in doubt, rtfm: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html (`Return the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with using `.count` or `.find` is you do not find overlapping strings:

```
>>> "banana".find("ana")
1
>>> "banana".count("ana")
1
```

You can do something like this:

```
>>> g="Canada's bananas analysis"
>>> sub_string="ana"
>>> [1 for i in range(0, len(g)-len(sub_string)) if g[i:i+len(sub_string)]==sub_string] 
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Or, more step by step:

```
>>> count=0
>>> for i in range(0, len(g)-len(sub_string)):
...     if g[i:i+len(sub_string)]==sub_string:
...         count+=1
... 
>>> count
4
```

Comment: thank you. This is along the lines I was exploring but couldn't wrap my head around g[i:blah] now that you pointed out I see it and can't understand why I did not see it b4! ---- g[i:i+len(sub_string)] IS SWEET 2C IT!--- Everybody has been helpful, I have learned a lot tonight  and need to practice  and let it steep. Thanks to  inspectorG4dget,dawg,Tané Tachyon,Pier Paolo
 Ulrich Eckhardt , F1Rumors  for the generosity of knowledge and time. I tried & am studying all your examples.

Answer (score 2):

Re "Don't need the exact answer just the idea", what you want here is regular expressions ("Import re") using lookahead.

Or you certainly could do something like:

```
for i in range(lenG - len(b)):
    if g[i:i + len(b)] == b:
```

(I just like to use regular expressions. :-))

Answer (score 1):

If I were to program the procedure myself, I'd use the `find()` method of `str` objects. Its syntax is:

```
<string_name>.find(substring [, index])
```

where `index` is the (optional) index of the character where to start the search *from*, and the return value is the index of the *first* match (or -1 if there were no matches).

So, a simple algorithm could be:

```
idx <- 0          # start from the beginning of the string
count <- 0        # number of matches
while True:
    idx <- index_of_next_match # returned by the find() method
    check_idx()   # check return value of find()
    if idx_is_OK:
        idx++     # otherwise find() returns always the same match
        count++
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do this with a regex.  Trick is, to capture overlapping matches, you have to use a look ahead assertion instead of a regular match.  For this example, it would look like the following:

```
src="Canada's bananas analysis"
x = re.compile(r'(?=ana)', re.IGNORECASE)
f = x.findall(src)
print len(f)

4
```